# Opening an .htaccess file in Eclipse opens a new instance of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm unable to open any .htaccess file in Eclipse while Eclipse is open without causing Eclipse to open a new instance of Eclipse. If I drag the file from my folder to Eclipse it triggers a new instance to open. For all other files, the existing instance of Eclipse would simply open the file.

- Windows 7
- Eclipse PDT 2.1 SR-2

Any ideas?

Comment: What OS are you using?  What version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you've set up Eclipse to use the OS-defined editor to open it, and then told Windows to use Eclipse?

To be sure: right-click the file in Windows and see what "Open with" gives you.

To fix it: change the file association in Preferences » General » Editors » File Associations, to make Eclipse use some built-in editor. (Or, if that doesn't work: right-click the file in the Eclipse Navigator, and ensure that Open With does not have System Editor selected.)